# How to count values in a query result

Tags: sql, database, count, sybase

I want to count the values on a query result but within the same query if that makes sense. the origional query is

```
SELECT CLOSING_FEE+CLOSING_FEE_INT+CLOSING_INS+CLOSING_INT+CLOSING_OTHER as BAL, total_closing_balance
FROM statement
```

this returns over 4000 rows. I want to check the two add up. is there a way to use the count function in the same query to count the first two values of the select statement?

Or would i have to use something like a temp table and then count?

Comment: your total closing balance is static ?

Comment: in this is not static what should its value aggregate to.. I mean it shuold be sum of 4000 records or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if total_closing_balance is static

```
 SELECT SUM(CLOSING_FEE+CLOSING_FEE_INT+CLOSING_INS+CLOSING_INT+CLOSING_OTHER) as BAL, MAX(total_closing_balance) AS total_closing_balance FROM isql.VW_300_statement WHERE brand = '1'AND DAT = '2013-01-18 00:00:00.00000'AND INS_TYPE =''group by Brand,DAT
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Select sum(CLOSING_FEE+CLOSING_FEE_INT+CLOSING_INS+CLOSING_INT+CLOSING_OTHER )`

it will add up all these details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to count the rows of a query result you have to write a query as following:

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT CLOSING_FEE+CLOSING_FEE_INT+CLOSING_INS+CLOSING_INT+CLOSING_OTHER as BAL, total_closing_balance
FROM isql.VW_300_statement
WHERE brand = '1'
AND DAT = '2013-01-18 00:00:00.00000'
AND INS_TYPE ='')
```